# Highlighting an textbox server control on focus

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a textbox, when clicked I want the text to highlight:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="searchInput" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
```

I am trying to add the functionality via C#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    searchInput.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "javascript:this.select();");
}
```

I am not getting the desired result however. WHen I click the box the text is not highlighting. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Edit:

To clarify I want the text selected.

Comment: What do you mean by "highlight"?  You want to change the background color of the textbox?  The text color?  You want the text to be selected as though the user had selected it with the mouse?

Comment: I want the text to be selected, sorry for not being clear.

Comment: This works if you tab into it per my testing, not not if you click because when you click you alter the caret position.

Comment: How do you do it by clicking?

Comment: One method is to use `setTimeout()` to force your `select()` call to fire after the browser is finished doing whatever it does when you focus into the field. You can use `0` milliseconds to fire the delayed function immediately after the native handler executes. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click into the box you may alter the caret position and therefore alter the text selection range.

Try this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    searchInput.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "var elem=this;setTimeout(function(){elem.select();},0);");
}
```

By forcing a wait via `setTimeout()` you can `select()` the text after the native focus event fires and set the selection range back to the text `value`.

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mxn3F/

Answer (score 0):

I always highlight by changing the BackColor to yellow. You can try that it should work.

Comment: I believe the OP is trying to get the textbox highlighted so that they can potentially erase what is in there.  Setting the background to yellow will not help.  Especially since there is no code example on how to do this.

Comment: I noticed that after i posted that is why i tried to delete this post. Internet is horrible at my house i must not of deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try following code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="searchInput" runat="server"  OnFocus="this.style.borderColor='red'" OnBlur="this.style.borderColor=''"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: This does not select the text. The question doesn't mention changing the border color of the text box.

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood the question actually. Question was not very clear before making the edit.